# yet another python subprocess monitor stdout in real time

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess

I know that I am asking yet another question about this topic so I must be dense.  I cannot get the following code example to display the output of my long running subprocess while it is running (in real-time).  The code works, the thread starts, the subprocess executes, however all the output is only displayed after the subprocess exits.  It hangs at the `line = self.proc.stdout.readline()` line until the subprocess completes.

This is my first Python application and I am running this on Windows using Python 3.6.  I have read as many of the subprocess answers as I can find and I have read the subprocess source and documentation, but I am unable to make it work when the all the answers say that it should.  What part of this concept am I not getting?

```
#! python

import sys
import os
import subprocess
import shlex
from threading import Thread

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

##############################################################
class ExternalProc(QDialog):

    outputUpdate = pyqtSignal(str)
    procFinished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ExternalProc, self).__init__(parent)

        self.procFinished.connect(self.stop)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        grpBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        outputTextGrpBox = QGroupBox("Process Output")        

        self.outputText = QTextEdit(outputTextGrpBox)
        self.outputText.setReadOnly(True)
        self.outputText.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        grpBoxLayout.addWidget(self.outputText, 1)
        outputTextGrpBox.setLayout(grpBoxLayout)

        vbox.addWidget(outputTextGrpBox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.outputUpdate.connect(self.AppendOutput)
        self.setWindowTitle("Process Output")
        self.show()

    def AppendOutput(self, str):
        self.outputText.append(str)
        QApplication.processEvents()

    def runProc(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(self.command, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True,  
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        while self.proc.poll() is None:
            line = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            self.outputUpdate.emit(line.rstrip())

        #for line in iter(self.proc.stdout.readline, ""):
        #    self.outputUpdate.emit(line.rstrip())

        self.procFinished.emit()
        print("debug: proc thread stopping")

    def start(self, cmd):
        self.command = cmd
        self.procThread = Thread(target=self.runProc)
        self.procThread.start()
        print("debug: proc thread started")

    def stop(self):
        self.proc.stdout.close()
        self.procThread.join()
        print("debug: proc thread stopped")

##############################################################
class LaunchProc(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        cmdGrpBox = QGroupBox("Process Command", self)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        cmdLabel = QLabel("Command:", cmdGrpBox)
        cmdLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(cmdLabel)

        self.cmdText = QLineEdit(cmdGrpBox)
        hbox.addWidget(self.cmdText, 1)

        cmdBtn = QPushButton("Launch", cmdGrpBox)
        cmdBtn.setDefault(True)
        cmdBtn.clicked.connect(self.launchCmd)
        hbox.addWidget(cmdBtn)

        cmdGrpBox.setLayout(hbox)

        vbox.addWidget(cmdGrpBox)
        vbox.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setWindowTitle("Long Running Process")
        self.center()

        self.show()

    def center(self):        
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def launchCmd(self):
        launchDlg = ExternalProc(self)
        args = shlex.split(self.cmdText.text())
        launchDlg.start(args)

##############################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = LaunchProc()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This won't necessarily work. Commonly the child process detects that stdout is a pipe and enables full buffering on stdout, which is typically a 4 KiB buffer. In Linux you can try to run the program using `stdbuf` to set line buffering. Nothing like that exists in Windows, or would even be practical considering the number of CRTs that are possible in a single process.

Comment: DOh!  You're exactly right.  Since I have control of the 'long running app' that I am trying to monitor, I modified it's stdout to not buffer and now it works as desired.  Thanks for the tip.